# Color discrepancy when using Android emulator, real device and Gimp on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, colors

When I set a background color **#FF7200C2** in any Layout in Android, I thought I would get:

[image: cyan]

This looks so in Gimp as well as in graphical Android editor in Eclipse. But when I launch the app on emulator or a real device it looks like this:

[image: blue]

Why does it differ and what is the correct color now?
It's very strange, when I try to make a screenshot from the emulator, on the screenshot it looks different than on the emulator: On the screenshot it's the same as the first color, on the emulator it's like the second color)

Maybe this is a problem with the underlying OS, Ubuntu. Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the alpha from the color,ie remove the "ff"

Comment: It's the same. Before I didn't have the alpha channel set.

Comment: Thats wired bro,Ive tried this on my device and its giving me the correct color.Maybe your marchine is in bgr instead of rgb,try to use this instead,0072C2

Comment: I figured out that's a screen problem. When I drag the emulator from the laptop screen to my monitor, it's cyan. On the laptop and Android device it's kind of blue. Very strange.

Comment: try to use #0072C2 and see whether it will give you the opposite effect